# .GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray() differences in values

Tags: arrays, format, gdal

I have been trying to filter MODIS images with quality control. The script now works as it's supposed to except for the opening of the images (tif).

I use GDal :

```
 o_image= gdal.Open(path_image)
 a_image = o_image.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

to open and read as array, the problem is the fact that the values in the array are between 13 000 and 14 000 where in reality between 0 and 255. Do you have any clue on what's going on ?

I get it should be something about format but I don't know where to look and how to change it.

o_image returns :

```
<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x7fc80533c030> >
```

GetDriver() returns :

```
<osgeo.gdal.Driver; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDriverShadow *' at 0x7fc80533c030> >
```

Not sure how to use GDalInfo() to be honest. I tried to put it in a variable, as follows :

```
X = Gdalinfo(path_to_image)
```

or without a variable but it returns

```
NameError : name 'gdalinfo' is not defined. Did you mean: 'geoinfo' ?
```

Thanks in advance

the whole code if you want more precisions :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on

@author: sarah
"""
###############################################################################
from osgeo import gdal
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
###############################################################################

def tri_MOD(list_chemin):
    global chemins_LST, chemins_QC
    chemins_LST=[]
    chemins_QC=[]
    for chemin in list_chemin:
        image = chemin.split('/')[-1] 
        if image.split('_')[2] == "LST":
            chemins_LST.append(chemin)
        else: #tester de commenter et voir si cela fonctionne
            chemins_QC.append(chemin)
    return(chemins_LST)


def processing_LST(chemins_LST, folder_out):
    
    global data_lst, col, row, geoinfo, projinfo, data_result #pour éviter l'erreur UnboundLocalError : local variable referenced before assignment 
    col = []
    data_result=[]
    row = []
    geoinfo =[]
    projinfo=[]

    for LST in chemins_LST: 

    # une boucle ne fonctionne pas, on cherche donc à trouver les images QC à partir des images LST 
    
        idx_lst = LST.find('LST_')
        tif = LST.split('_')[-1]
        doy = LST.split('_')[-2]
        mod = LST.split('_')[-4]
        QC = LST[:idx_lst] + 'QC_' + mod + '_' + doy + '_' + tif

    # ouverture des images  

        f_lst = gdal.Open(LST)
        data_lst = f_lst.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
        data_lst = data_lst * 1.0
        f_qc = gdal.Open(QC)        

    # creation du fichier de sorti

        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
        col = f_lst.GetRasterBand(1).XSize
        row = f_lst.GetRasterBand(1).YSize
        f_out = driver.Create(folder_out + 'K_' + LST.split('/')[-1], xsize = col, ysize = row, bands = 1, eType = gdal.GDT_Float32)
        f_out.SetGeoTransform(f_lst.GetGeoTransform())
        f_out.SetProjection(f_lst.GetProjection())

    # lecture des images qc et gestion du filtre
        data_qc = f_qc.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
        data_qc = data_qc * 1.0
        data_qc[data_qc < 90] = 1
        data_qc[data_qc > 89] = np.nan

    #application du filtre sur les lst par la multiplication 
        data_result = (data_qc*data_lst)
        data_result[data_result == 0] = np.nan

        f_out.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data_result)
        f_out.FlushCache()
        QC =+1

    LST=+1

    return(data_result)
```

I tried to look at the documentation of GDal but don't really know how to ask the internet about it

EDIT :

For people who wonder about it when you use MODIS data from Appeears if you want your results to be in kelvin you have to apply the scale factor which is indicated in the metadata.

For me, it worked as such :

```
f_lst = gdal.Open(path_to_image) 
scalef = float(f_lst.GetMetadata()['scale_factor'])
data_lst = f_lst.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()* scalef
```

Comment: You can use `gdalinfo <path_image>` on a command line, or `gdal.Info(path_image)` from Python. It's impossible to answer without any information about the data you're using.